# How to most efficiently correct Gamma value of Qimages/QPixmaps or QGraphicsView or QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsProxyWidget in PySide (Qt4, Python)?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, qt4, pyside

I am trying to change the gamma value of of a video widget (Phonon.VideoWidget) displayed in a QGraphicsView via a proxy. I noticed the QGraphicsEffect from QtGui works on it via proxy but there are only defaults for blur, single color overlay, and drop shadow. Phonon.VideoWidget itself has options for brightness, contrast, and even hue that work great but no options for gamma correction strangely. QGraphicsEffects are not very fast but they definitely works with the videowidget playing media via graphicsproxy. I decided I would start by creating my own QGraphicsEffect but at the current state it does not seem possible.

I started with something simpler, a single QPixmap (I take the QImage from it. Since QGraphicsEffect seems to work primarily with QPixmaps in its virtual draw function I figure this is a good place to start) and gamma correcting that. It worked. However, it is currently far too slow even with numpy (setPixel for QImage is even slower), taking 5 seconds or more to convert one 1200x900, 400kb jpg image.

The way I do it is I create a list of gamma converted values from 0-255 based on the gamma value entered. Then using numpy, with the QImage from the pixmap, I create an array that points to the image data and finally edit each pixel with it's corresponding value on the table (so no extra calculations are made for each pixel). The meat of the code is as follows

```
gammaTable = []

for i in xrange(256):
    gammaPixel = CorrectGamma( i, gammaValue ) #returns numpy.int8 or int, works properly
    gammmaTable.append(gammaPixel)

qimage = myPixmap.toImage()
bytes = qimage.bits() #qimage.constBits()
imageBytes = numpy.asarray(bytes).reshape(qimage.width(), qimage.height(), 4)

#Change each pixel      
for x in xrange(qimage.width()):
    for y in xrange(qimage.height()):
        imageBytes[x,y,0] = gammmaTable[imageBytes[x,y,0]] #gammaDictionary[imageBytes[x,y,0]]
        imageBytes[x,y,1] = gammmaTable[imageBytes[x,y,1]] #gammaDictionary[imageBytes[x,y,1]]
        imageBytes[x,y,2] = gammmaTable[imageBytes[x,y,2]] #gammaDictionary[imageBytes[x,y,2]]
        imageBytes[x,y,3] = gammmaTable[imageBytes[x,y,3]] #gammaDictionary[imageBytes[x,y,3]]

return qimage
```

I only run it once at the start of the program, and it works, but it is far too slow. I also tried using QImage.scanLine() but I honestly am not sure how to use it and there is no setScanLine() function to work with either. constScanLine returns an uneditable array. Another thing in the defaults I looked into was QImage.colorTable(). However, they are always empty for me so I wasn't able to work with them.

I am considering trying to OpenCV for python but I am not sure if it will suit my needs but I did see a youtube video earlier of some person claiming to use Qt and OpenCV to create what seemed like an overlay (looked to be a noisefilter and nightfilter) over a video stream in a widget, and that is more or less what I need. It did not say anything about it however and could have been C++ Qt (I am working Python and Qt4, via PySide).

I have a good feeling that if I did not do something wrong that maybe Python is too slow for this. Currently the bottleneck seems to be that it takes a long time to iterate and change each value of the numpy imageBytes array that points to the QImage's data array. I don't know how to work with C++ and compiling for PySide/Python and I'm not sure if even if I could that I can even translate this to C++ especially when it comes to the idea of dealing with pointers and sharing between Python and C++.

I also have a feeling I am missing out on a solution somewhere but I have not discovered any other options to think about or try. I was perhaps thinking that maybe I could put some kind of overlay over the graphics items but I realize it makes little sense and there seems to be no such thing (closest is QGraphicsEffect).